# How do I intentionally read from main memory vs cache?

Tags: performance, caching, assembly, masm

So I am being taught assembly and we have an assignment which is to find the time difference between reading from memory and reading from cache. We have to do this by creating 2 loops and timing them. (one reads from main memory and the other from cache). The thing is, I don't know and can't find anything that tells me how to read from either cache or main memory =/. Could you guys help me? I'm doing this in MASM32. I understand how to make loops and well most of the assembly language but I just can't make it read =/

---

**Edit:**

I have a question, I've done this ...

```
mov ecx, 100 ;loop 100 times
xor eax, eax ;set eax to 0
_label:
mov eax, eax ;according to me this is read memory is that good?
dec ecx ;dec loop
jnz _label ;if still not equal to 0 goes again to _label
```

... would that be ok?

---

**Edit 2:**

well then, I don't intend to pry and I appreciate your help, I just have another question, since these are two loops I have to do. I need to compare them somehow, I've been looking for a timer instruction but I haven't found any I've found only: **timeGetTime**, **GetTickCount** and **Performance Counter** but as far as I understand these instructions return the system time not the time it takes for the loop to finish. Is there a way to actually do what I want? or I need to think of another way?

Also, to read from different registers in the second loop (the one not reading from cache) is it ok if I give various "mov" instructions? or am I totally off base here?

Sorry for all this questions but again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read from cache. have a loop which reads from the same (or very similar) memory address:

- The first time you read from that address, the values from that memory address (and from other, nearby memory address) will be moved into cache
- The **next** time you read from that **same** address, the values are already cached and so you're reading from cache.

To read uncached memory, have a loop which reads from many, very different (i.e. further apart than the cache size) memory addresses.

---

To answer your second question:

- The things you're doing with ecx and jnz look OK (I don't know how accurate/sensitive your timer is, but you might want to loop more than 100 times)
- The `mov eax, eax` is not "read memory" ... it's a no-op, which moves eax into eax. Instead, I think that the MASM syntax for reading from memory is something more like `mov eax,[esi]` ("read the from the memory location whose address is contained in `esi`")
- Depending on what O/S you're using, you must read from a memory address which actually exists and is readable. On Windows, for example, an application wouldn't be allowed to do `mov esi, 0` followed by `mov eax, [esi]` because an application isn't allowed to read the memory whose address/location is zero.

---

To answer your third question:

> timeGetTime, GetTickCount and Performance Counter

Your mentioning timeGetTime, GetTickCount and Performance Counter implies that you're running under Windows.

Yes, these return the current time, to various resolutions/accuracies: for example, GetTickCount has a resolution of about 50 msec, so it fails to time events which last less than 50 msec, is inaccurate when timing events which last only 50-100 msec. That's why I said that `100` in your `ecx` probably isn't big enough.

The `QueryPerformanceCounter` function is probably the most accurate timer that you have.

To use any of these timers as an interval timer:

- Get the time, before you start to loop
- Get the time again, after you finish looping
- Subtract these two times: the difference is the time interval

> is it ok if I give various "mov" instructions?

Yes I think so. I think you can do it like this (beware I'm not sure/don't remember whether this is the right MASM syntax for reading from a name memory location) ...

```
mov eax,[memory1]
mov eax,[memory2]
mov eax,[memory3]
mov eax,[memory4]
mov eax,[memory5]
```

... where `memory1` through `memory5` are addresses of widely-spaced global variables in your data segment.

Or, you could do ...

```
mov eax,[esi]
add esi,edx
mov eax,[esi]
add esi,edx
mov eax,[esi]
add esi,edx
mov eax,[esi]
add esi,edx
mov eax,[esi]
```

... where esi is pointing to the bottom of a long chunk of memory, and edx is some increment that's equal to about a fifth of the length of the chunk.